# SQL Server error conversion failed when converting the varchar value to datatype int

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    BG_BUG_ID, BG_SUMMARY, BG_STATUS, BG_USER_14, BG_USER_39,
    BG_USER_03, BG_PROJECT, BG_DETECTED_BY, BG_USER_09
FROM 
    QC11_tests_defects_db.td.BUG
WHERE 
    BG_BUG_ID IN ('" & Replace(Mid(Tmp_List, 1, Len(Tmp_List) - 1), ";", "',')
```

I get an error :

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to datatype int

Please I need help :)

Comment: is `'" & Replace(Mid(Tmp_List, 1, Len(Tmp_List) - 1), ";", "',')´ also a SQL Expression?

Comment: You cannot use the `IN` operator this way, i.e. against a string containing comma separated values. You have to use a list of values instead.

Comment: You can not use this kind of Expression in sql

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use Tablue Valued Parameters.

First, you would need to create a table type to use with the procedure:

```
create type dbo.Id_udt as table (Id int not null);
go
```

Then, create the procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.bug_get_fromlist (
  @Id_udt as dbo.Id_udt readonly
) as 
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on;

  select bg_bug_id, bg_summary, bg_status, bg_user_14, bg_user_39,
         bg_user_03, bg_project, bg_detected_by, bg_user_09
  from qc11_tests_defects_db.td.bug
  /* or use an inner join */
  where bg_bug_id in (
    select id
    from @Id_udt i
    );

end;
go
```

Table Valued Parameters Reference:

- [Table-Valued Parameters - msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [User-Defined Table Types - msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators: A Match Made In Heaven! - Leonard Lobel](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)
- [Table Value Parameter Use With C# - Jignesh Trivedi](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-value-parameter-use-with-C-Sharp/)
- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)

---

Alternatively, you could split the string and use it like a table.

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden and conditional aggregation:

```
select bg_bug_id, bg_summary, bg_status, bg_user_14, bg_user_39,
       bg_user_03, bg_project, bg_detected_by, bg_user_09
from qc11_tests_defects_db.td.bug
where bg_bug_id in (
  select s.item 
  from dbo.delimitedsplit8K(@tmp_list,';') s
  )
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

---

`delimitedsplit8K` by Jeff Moden.

```
create function [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K] (
      @pstring varchar(8000)
    , @pdelimiter char(1)
  )
returns table with schemabinding as
 return
  with e1(N) as (
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
  )
  , e2(N) as (select 1 from e1 a, e1 b)
  , e4(N) as (select 1 from e2 a, e2 b)
  , ctetally(N) as (
    select top (isnull(datalength(@pstring),0)) 
      row_number() over (order by (select null)) from e4
  )
  , ctestart(N1) as (
    select 1 union all
    select t.N+1 from ctetally t where substring(@pstring,t.N,1) = @pdelimiter
  )
  , ctelen(N1,L1) as (
    select s.N1,
      isnull(nullif(charindex(@pdelimiter,@pstring,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
    from ctestart s
  )
 select itemnumber = row_number() over(order by l.N1)
      , item       = substring(@pstring, l.N1, l.L1)
   from ctelen l
;
go
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. but don't work because i have SQL Server 2012 is very old :(

Comment: Except for `string_split()`, these solutions work on SQL Server 2012.